# What is the number of solution of equation of locus when a straight line is tangent to the locus.

Tags: locus, discriminant

Find the values of $t$ if a straight line $y=t$ is the tangent to the locus of point $P$ ,
$$x^2+y^2+4x-6y-3=0$$
where $t$ is a constant.

This is an exam question from a school. The solution in the answer scheme is substitute the $t$ into the equation of locus, then use the discriminant (one solution) to find the values of $t$.

I assume the locus touches only one point of the tangent line, $y=t$ , so there is only one solution, and the final answer given is $t=-1$ and $t=7$.

but doesn't the number of solution refer to the number of point that intersect with the x-axis?

So when $y=0$,
$$x^2+4x-3=0$$
there should be two solutions, instead of one solution only, the values of $t$ should be  $t < -1$ and $t > 7$

So which one is correct?

Comment: The equation $y=t$ is not the equation of a straight line. Please review your question.

Comment: hmm.. I don't get it, may I know why is that not the equation of a straight line?

Comment: the straight line is tangent to the locus, and since the equation is _y=t_ , I assume it is a horizontal line. So I could just substitute the _y_ in the equation of locus with _t_

Comment: Why is _y_ increasing with the parameter? I thought the equation _y=t_ is another equation of straight line other than the equation of locus which that straight line is tangent to the locus as question mentioned.

Comment: I'm sorry if there is any misunderstanding, that's just what I understand about the question, if the way I think is wrong, then what should be done to answer this question？or there is misinformation？

Comment: @coudy $y=t$ for a fixed $t$ **is indeed** the equation of a (horizontal) straight line.

Comment: Ah, indeed, I understand at last. I thought it was the equation of a straight line in parameterisation form. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @coudy that's ok, appreciate for trying to correct me

Comment: so why is there only one solution while using discriminant to find the values of $t$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two horizontal lines tangent to the ellipse are $y=-1$ and $y=7$ as you found. The horizontal line $y=0$, which is the x-axis, cuts the ellipse in two points as you noticed.

The discriminant is $\Delta = -4(t+1)(t-7)$. It is positive when $t$ lies between $-1$ and $7$, as expected. May be you forgot the minus sign?

Comment: if the x-axis cuts the ellipse in two points, the discriminant should be greater than zero right? but why is the discriminant equals to zero?

Comment: For $t=0$, the discriminant is equal to $-4(0+1)(0-7) = 28$.

Comment: I mean why is $Δ=−4(t+1)(t−7)$ , but not $Δ<−4(t+1)(t−7)$ ?

Comment: $Delta$ is the discriminant of the equation $x^2+4x+(t^2-6t-3)$. The solution(s) $x$ of this equation, as a function of $t$, are the abscissa of the points at the intersection of the horizontal line of height $t$ with the ellipse. If $\Delta$ is zero, there is a single point of intersection and the horizontal line is tangent to the ellipse.

Comment: so the equation already consists of variable $t$ , no more variable $y$ in the equation, we can see this equation as the function of $t$ instead, am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Solving the equation gives you the abscissa of the points both on the horizontal line at height $t$ and on the ellipse. If there is a single abscissa, there is a single point of intersection and so the line is tangent to the ellipse.

Comment: Ok, got it, I finally understand, thank you so much, you make my day!